# When I run train_net.py of fast rcnn,the code cracked

Tags: python, memory, caffe, object-detection, object-detection-api

[Here is when the code crack:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8XRW.png)

I0303 14:17:35.769629 17352 net.cpp:774] Copying source layer loss_cls

I0303 14:17:35.770619 17352 net.cpp:774] Copying source layer loss_bbox

Solving...

[And then I use VS2013 to see where exist the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjEMU.png)

```
template <typename Dtype>
const Dtype* Blob<Dtype>::gpu_data() const {
CHECK(data_);//here exist the error of unable to read the memory
return (const Dtype*)data_->gpu_data();
}
```

Why the code unable to read memory,what's wrong?How could I solve the problem?

[this is the pre-train parameter I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1is6.png)

The memory of my GPU is 6GB,which is enough for the code.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the code? Please take the time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. For instance, please don't post pictures of code and error messages, post the text directly here on SO.